# Get informed if a new mail arrives in node.js with IMAP

Tags: node.js, email, events, imap

I would like to create a module in node.js that will inform me (with an event) if a new mail arrives (using IMAP). Until now i have used IMAP module example code but can anyone help me for the next step? Thanks a lot.

```
var Imap = require('imap'),
    inspect = require('util').inspect;

var imap = new Imap({
  user: 'mygmailname@gmail.com',
  password: 'mygmailpassword',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});

function openInbox(cb) {
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;

/* ??? */


 });

});


imap.once('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

imap.once('end', function() {
  console.log('Connection ended');
});

imap.connect();
```

Comment: What is the next step is too broad a question.  What is the specific issue you are having?

Comment: i would like to get informed if a new message arrives and then to have it's header and content appeared on the screen. thank you for your interest!

Comment: Seems like the user wants to create an email listener which will call a callback function whenever a new mail arrives.

Comment: Here is how to get notification for each email
`
imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function (err, box) {
    if (err){
     throw err;
    } 
    else{
    imap.on('mail', function (num){
     console.log("New message arrived: ", num);
    });     
    }
  });
 });
` Then use fetch method to read the mail

Comment: when using the above snippet the 'connection ended' message only fired!

Answer (score 1):

Read [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501). Without understanding the IMAP protocol, there is absolutely no chance that one might implement an IMAP-speaking client using some IMAP library.

Alternatively, look for some high-level library which abstracts away the IMAP protocol from you, and provides some unified API of their own.